# Unable to map the step definition glued code

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, bdd

I'm having a problem mapping the glue code from my Feature file to step definition code.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(`enter code here`
features = "Features/store.feature"
,glue={"com.test.stepdefinitions/Store.java"}
,monochrome = true
,format={"junit:reports/junit/reports.xml","pretty", "html:reports/html","json:reports/json/Store_reports.json"}

)
public class StoreRunner {

}
```

When I run this, it will throw this console message:

Feature: Store

Scenario: Delete item from checkout page # Features/store.feature:3

Given the user is in the checkout page # null
                           # null

Comment: The glue value needs to be in package format only. Remove the "/Store.java" part. Also use plugin instead of format. Can you add the folder structure of the project. If you are using a maven project then the feature option might need to be changed

Comment: Thanks @Grasshopper for the help. If I remove the "Store.java" on glue parameter, it will not able to determine which specific feature file to be run.

Comment: u can mention the feature fie to run in the the features ooption or by fitering using tags.

Answer (score 1):

Aprreciate your help guys. I'm able to solve this issue using the latest cucumber version 3.1.0 from io.cucumber and latest selenium jar file from seleniumhq.

Here's my code:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = "Features/store.feature"
,glue={"com.bitpoints.stepdefinitions"}
,monochrome = true
,format={"junit:reports/junit/reports.xml","pretty", "html:reports/html","json:reports/json/Login_reports.json"}

)

public class StoreRunner {

}
```

As you can see I've included "Features/store.feature" in features and it was able to pick the store feature file to be run.

Hope this helps

[image: Running store feature file]

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question if you are using Maven or not but looking at the *reports* I presume are using *Maven*.

To map the glue code from the *Feature file* to *Step Definition* you need to format the *Test Runner* class as follows :

- Mention the directory name containing the *FeatureFile* instead of providing full path.
- The value of *glue* should be set to directory name containing the *StepDefinitionClass* instead of full path.
- Move the *format* attributes within `plugin` argument.
- Your *Test Runner* class file will look like :

  ```
  @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
  @CucumberOptions(
      features="Features",
      glue={"stepdefinitions"},
      monochrome = true,
      plugin={"junit:reports/junit/reports.xml"
              "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.text",
              "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
              "json:target/cucumber.json",
              "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json",
      )
  public class ReportTestRunner 
  {
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code:

```
 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/features/",  glue = {"steps"}, plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json"})
    public class RunFeaturesTest {}
```

project architecture :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is mentions the Step-definition class name in @CucumberOptions.

Here is the format

```
@CucumberOptions
{
feature={"path of feature file with extension"},
glue={"Step-definition package Name.class-Name"}
}
```